# How to send a created XML file to specific URL with POST method in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, post

I'm creating an XML file and want to send it to an external URL(that starts a PDF download) using POST method without using the form.
I have this form example that I'm trying to avoid.

```
  <form action="https://www.szamlazz.hu/szamla/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  XML állomány: <input type="file" name="action-xmlagentxmlfile"><br><br>
  E-mail értesítő küldés esetén:<br>
  <input type="submit" name="generate" value="Számla generálás">
```

This is how I'm creating my file that I want to send.

```
$created_xml = ($xmlBuilder->getXML());
   file_put_contents(
        $order_id.".xml",
        $created_xml,
    );
```

Comment: You want to POST a file to a third-party site through code instead of using their form to do so?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP, cURL, and HTTP POST example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-and-http-post-example)

Comment: You could add it as a mime attachment.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)

Comment: @GregSchmidt Yes, I want to POST a file to a third-party site through code instead of using their form. 
Cauze this function will be added to a commerce website and the user does not need the xml file, he directly needs the pdf

Comment: Then the link I provided should give you all the details you need.